# lbfgs - Call in C++

Tags: c++, r, optimization, rcpp

The `lbfgs` package in R is an implementation of a C++ LBFGS optimizer using Rcpp. Based on [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lbfgs/vignettes/Vignette.pdf) tutorial, we can write C++ codes as strings in R, compile them using `inline`, and then pass them into the `lbfgs` function. But is it possible to directly call the function in C++, maybe using something like `// [[Rcpp::depends(lbfgs)]]`?

Thanks.

Comment: Generally speaking the package author would have to provide an interface (via header file) in a subdirectory of `inst/`. Looking at [the package layout](https://github.com/cran/lbfgs), this is not the case, so `// [[Rcpp::depends(lbfgs)]]` will not work. You could certainly download the package in source format and modify it accordingly to achieve this, however.

Comment: @paulsm4 Please, no.  That link points to a dated post with faulty recommendations.  Friends don't let friends use `.C()`.  You can use C or C++ as you see fit, with or without Rcpp, but you **always** want `.Call()` which is (of course) also a C-level interface.

Comment: Look at my RcppDE package -- also implementing an optimizer -- and its ability to pass user-defined objective functions down via external pointers.  User compiles them locally, or demand or in advance, or you compile in the package, or ...

Comment: Presently, there is no nice way of going about using lbfgs without using either RcppNumerical (dependency Eigen) or using RcppMLPACK (dependency RcppArmadillo that is stuck at 1.0.10 w/ Rcout issues). As a result, I'm actively working on bringing an LBFGS interface to R in a portable mechanic for RcppArmadillo related activities. Should have something working mid-december if you can wait that long.